# perl: Can't use string as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use

Tags: arrays, perl

I have this problem where I'm trying to pass an array to a sub and it reads some other value. In this test script I'm passing a reference of array @players but its reading string $buffer instead.

```
use Data::Dumper;

my @players = [];
my @playerscores = [];
my %FORM;

my $buffer = "numplayers=2&changeplayers=3&CHANGEIT=CHANGEIT&player1=a&player2=b&restart=1&newcoords=";

sub testsub {
    my @testee = @$_[0];
    print "in testsub: $testee[0]\n";
}

my @holder = split(/&/,$buffer,);
foreach my $iter (@holder)
{
    my ($name,$value) = split(/=/,$iter);
    $FORM{$name} = $value;
}
$_ = $buffer;
foreach my $key (keys(%FORM))
{
    if($key=~ /player[1-9]/)
    {
        if(!($FORM{$key} eq ""))
        {
            my $holder = $key;
            $holder =~ s/player//;
            $players[$holder] = $FORM{$key};
            $playerscores[$holder] = 0;
            $_ = $buffer;
        }
    }
}

print "\n Data Dumper on player:\n";
print Dumper(@players);
print "\n\n";

print "Check sub:\n";
testsub(\@players,\@playerscores);
```

output:

```
 Data Dumper on player:
$VAR1 = [];
$VAR2 = 'a';
$VAR3 = 'b';


Check sub:
Can't use string ("numplayers=2

&changeplayers=3&CHA"...) as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use at test-str-pool2.pl line 15.
```

Whereas I was expecting "a" or "b" as the result of `print "in testsub: $testee[0]\n";`. Why is this happening?

Comment: Your code as you have it listed does not currently report that error.

Comment: I left out `use strict; use warnings;`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're declaring your arrays wrongly which is why the Dumper output has `[]` (an empty array reference) as the first element in `@players`. Use:

```
my @players = ();
my @playerscores = ();
```

The second error comes from:

```
my @testee = @$_[0];
```

This attempts to dereference `$_` and take the first element from the resulting array. You mean:

```
my @testee = @{$_[0]};
```

Which takes the first element from `@_` and dereferences it.

Answer (score 2):

There are several things you're doing wrong.

You have `player1` and `player2`. You are using an array to hold them, and removing the `player` string to get the player number.

There is no `player0` which is why you're getting an `undef` in the first value of your array.

You are passing in two array references, but only looking at one, and looking at it in the wrong way too:

I prefer to do this:

```
sub testsub {
    my $testee_ref = shift;
    @testee = @{ $testee_ref };
```

I like using shift because it's more obvious what you're doing. I would prefer to use a two step approach (get the reference, then dereference that dereference). But, you could also use:

```
sub testsub {
    my @testee = @{shift()};
```

or

```
sub testsub {
    my @testee = @{$_[0]};   #Take the reference in $_[0] and dereference it.
```

Either way, you now get the error message:

```
Use of uninitialized value $testee[0] in concatenation (.) or string at ./test.pl line 40.
```

Because your the first element in your array is undefined!

It looks like you want to store the information about the player and their score in an easily accessible format. I would use a single reference to keep the player's *score*, their *name*, and all aspects of their game together in one place. You're already know about references because you're using them:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);
use Data::Dumper;

my $game = {};   # A reference to a game
$game->{PLAYERS} = {}; # A reference to the players
my $buffer = "numplayers=2&changeplayers=3&CHANGEIT=CHANGEIT&player1=a&player2=b&restart=1&newcoords=";

for my $values ( split /&/, $buffer ) {
    my ($key, $value ) = split /=/, $values;
    if ( $key !~ /^player/ ) {
        $game->{$key} = $value;
    }
    else {
        $game->{PLAYERS}->{$key}->{NAME} = $value;
        $game->{PLAYERS}->{$key}->{SCORE} = 0;
    }
}

say Dumper $game;

# Dumper a player
#

for my $player ( sort keys %{ $game->{PLAYERS} } ) {
    testsub( $game->{PLAYERS}->{$player} );
}

sub testsub {
    my $player_ref = shift;
    say "Player Name = " . $player_ref->{NAME};
    say "Player Score = " . $player_ref->{SCORE};
}
```

Running this will give you:

```
$VAR1 = {
        'newcoords' => '',
        'restart' => '1',
        'changeplayers' => '3',
        'numplayers' => '2',
        'PLAYERS' => {
                        'player2' => {
                                        'NAME' => 'b',
                                        'SCORE' => 0
                                    },
                        'player1' => {
                                        'NAME' => 'a',
                                        'SCORE' => 0
                                    }
                    },
        'CHANGEIT' => 'CHANGEIT'
        };

Player Name = a
Player Score = 0
Player Name = b
Player Score = 0
```

Note that I have a single variable called `$game` that stores all of the information about the game including all of the player information. Now, if I am given a reference to a player, I can print out that player's name and score.

Even better would be using [Object Oriented Perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlootut.html). All OOPerl does is use subroutines and *blessing* of references to manager these complex object types for you.

Comment: oh yeah... the dictionary. Yikes thats obvious. +1 sir.